# Static method and Public method performance comparison

Tags: c#

I have to create different methods to do custom comparison of two strings. Methods will be invoked later to order a list of strings by relevance values.

I was thinking about creating Static methods `compare1 , compare2...` inside a Static class `StringComparison` after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078021/performance-and-static-method-versus-public-method). But the thing is, The compare method will probably not being used at all. Only a few number of users will access compare functionality. Why do I keep objects hanging (Static `StringComparison`) in my app memory without being used most of the time?

So I decide to use a Lazy Singleton for `StringComparison` and make compare methods public.

Which is better (performance and design) static methods within static class or public methods within lazy singleton?

Am I paranoid about keeping static instances in memory without using them?

Comment: Yes, the whole question is completely nuts. You've plunged the art of premature optimization to a new nadir. I salute you.